# Vegetarian and vegan lifestyle and promotion

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, tags

I am wondering why this site does not consider promotion of vegetarianism and veganism as part of the vegetarian and vegan lifestyles, and, why is there not a [promotion](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/promotion) tag.

Comment: tags can't exist without questions. Do you know of suitable questions that we should tag? If so, please edit the question and add some links.

Comment: P.S. Welcome to the site. Nice to see active users.

Comment: I have several deleted posts which fit this category. However, they are deleted, and I don't really understand why.

Comment: They are deleted because you didn't edit them after they were closed. The closure reasons are given at the top of each post. If you want to discuss why a specific question was closed do ask a question about that question and link to it. Moderators can see deleted posts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly by "promotion of vegetarianism and veganism". Could you link to these deleted posts of yours that you mentioned?